# Java - Spigot - Change line of a Sign

Tags: plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I tried to develop something like [TeleportSigns](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/teleportsigns.29/) for my Minecraft-Server. But when I try to change a line of the sign, nothing happens.

This is the Code for changing the lines:

```
// loadTpSign
public static void loadTpSign(Sign sign) {
    sign.setLine(0, "\2474[\2476Minepedia\2474]");
    sign.update();
    sign.setLine(1, "\247f\247l" + sign.getLine(1));
    sign.update();
    sign.setLine(2, "\2478\247l" + Server.getPlayer(sign.getLine(1)) + "/" + Server.getMaxPlayers(sign.getLine(1)));
    sign.update();
    sign.setLine(3, Server.getStatus(sign.getLine(1).toLowerCase()));
    sign.update();
}
```

I run the method `loadTpSign` in this method:

```
// createTpSign
public static void createTpSign(Sign sign, String server) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConnection()
                .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TpSigns (world, x, y, z) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, sign.getWorld().getName());
        ps.setInt(2, sign.getX());
        ps.setInt(3, sign.getY());
        ps.setInt(4, sign.getZ());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    main.TpSignsList.add(new Location(sign.getWorld(), sign.getX(), sign.getY(), sign.getZ()));
    TpSigns.loadTpSign(sign);
}
```

And this method I run in the SignChangeEvent:

```
@EventHandler
public void onSignChange(SignChangeEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getPlayer() != null) {
        Player p = ev.getPlayer();
        if (p.hasPermission("tpsign")) {
            if (ev.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("[TPSIGN]")) {
                TpSigns.createTpSign((Sign) ev.getBlock().getState(), ev.getLine(1).toLowerCase());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to just update the sign once, after setting all lines, 
+ it is hard to help out while we don't know where you call it / in which contex

Comment: I also tried it with running sign.update() only once, too. But it also didn't work. I also updated my question, so you can see where I run the method.

Comment: TpSigns.createTpSign((Sign) ev.getBlock().getState(), ev.getLine(1).toLowerCase());                                                                                    Why exactly are you casting it to a blockstate?

Comment: I looked up "Block" in the JavaDoc and there it was said that you have to get the BlockState and cast it to a Sign to get a Sign